# "Mixed spaces and tabs error" and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (line 1)"

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

for my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756537/phonegap-android-native-function-not-getting-called-on-button-click), i did not get the error message so, copy pasted the code in jsbin.com , here i'm getting error in [jsbin output](http://jsbin.com/iFUCaKu/1/edit) as "Missed spaces and tabs" in `function fail(args) {
    failCallback(args);
     }` and also `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (line 1)"`.
for this piece of javascript code

Esocial.js

```
var SocialShare = function() {};
SocialShare.email = function(param, successCallback, failCallback) {

function success(args) {
    successCallback(args);
}

function fail(args) {
failCallback(args);
alert('Write Some real Text please.');
}

return PhoneGap.exec(function(args) {
    success(args);
}, function(args) {
    fail(args);
}, 'SocialShare', 'startEmailActivity', [param]);
};
```

Not able to rectify this error please help me...

html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum- scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="social.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Esocial.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }
 function onDeviceReady() 
{
 window.SocialShare = new SocialShare(); 
 console.log("in onDeviceReady");
  }


  function sendEmail()
  {
SocialShare.Email= function(param, successCallback, failCallback) {
    window.SocialShare.email({message:'Email body', subject: "Email Subject"},
        function(msg) {
        alert('Write Some real Text please.');
        },
        function(fail) {  

        }
    );
}
 }

</script>

  </head>

 <body onload="onLoad()">

<button onclick="sendEmail()" id="email">Email send </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try **var SocialShare =  {};** this may solve your problem